# Сериализация массива С#

Tags: c#, сериализация

Задача: создать xml файл на основании xsd схемы.
Имеется конструктор:

```html
    [XmlRoot("NBUSTATREPORT")]
    public class NbuStatReport
    {

        [XmlElement("HEAD")]
        public Head head
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("DATA")]
        public Data data
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }



    [XmlRoot("HEAD")]
    public class Head
    {

        [XmlElement("STATFORM")]
        public string statform
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("EDRPOU")]
        public string edrpou
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        [XmlElement("REPORTDATE")]
        public string reportdate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }


    [XmlRoot("DATA")]
    public class Data 
    {
        [XmlElement("EKP")]
        public string ekp
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("R030")]
        public string r030
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("T100")]
        public double t100
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

В теге НЕAD данные не измены, в теге DATA данные содержатся в двумерном массиве.
Необходимо сериализовать в файл xml данные как из HEAD, так из DATA, т.е. из двумерного массива.

С постоянными значениями все получилось, но как это сделать с массивом данных. Хэлп Плиз.

```html
public static void serial(string[,] s_Ar1, double[,] d_Ar2)
            {
                NbuStatReport nbuMain = new NbuStatReport {head = new Head { statform = "F7X", edrpou = "004565", reportdate = "28.05.2010" }, data = new Data {ekp = "100", r030 = "980", t100 = 556} };
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NbuStatReport));
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\WORK\new_4X.xml");
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, nbuMain);
                sw.Close();
            }
```

Comment: `создать xml файл на основании xsd схемы` - схема как выглядит?

Comment: Выложила схему: https://dropmefiles.com.ua/RNmM

Comment: То что вы выложили не является `XML Schema Definition (XSD)` это по всей видимости файл классов созданный программой `xsd.exe` на основании схемы xml. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530496

Comment: Да. То был файл, который я при помощи xsd.exe создала из этой схемы: https://dropmefiles.com.ua/7TfSB

Comment: XML, как и XSD, ни чего не знают ни о каких двумерных массивах. Вам нужно преобразовать ваш двумерный массив в список объектов. Все необходимые классы для этого у вас уже сгенерированы, осталось только заполнить. Ни чего от себя добавлять не требуется, ну разве что имена поправить для удобства, т.к. xsd.exe тупо склеивает имя класса из имен типов XSD в порядке их вложенности без разделителей. Если вы внимательно посмотрите XSD, то увидите, что элемент HEAD должен быть строго один, а количество элементов DATA не ограничено.

Comment: Тоже самое видно и по сгенерированным классам. Просто посмотрите внимательнее, поправьте имена, чтобы было читабельно и все поймете.